# Why Api Platform doesnt find anything by uuid SearchFilter

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I searched for hours now i cant figure out why api-platform SearchFilter doesnt find anything when searching for uuid.

At first the entity:

```
#[ApiResource]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['uuid' => 'exact', 'price' => 'exact', 'name' => 'partial'])]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]

class Product
{
  use UuidTrait;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->uuid = Uuid::v4();
  }
  //other entity Stuff here
}

trait UuidTrait
{
  #[ORM\Id]
  #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true, nullable: false)]
  private ?Uuid $uuid = null;

  public function getUuid(): ?Uuid
  {
      return $this->uuid;
  }

  public function getUuidBase32(): ?string
  {
      return $this->uuid?->toBase32();
  }
}
```

the endpoint `api/products/31343512-3456-7123-4567-123456712345` gives me the exact result. But when i now search by `/api/products?uuid[]=31343512-3456-7123-4567-123456712345` to search for more uuid's there are 0 results.
What is the reason for this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: are you sure your `SearchFilter` is from the  `Orm` namespace and not `Odm` namespace ?

Comment: the Searchfilter is from tze `ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter` namespace.